# match only letters after comma without numbers

Tags: regex, import.io

im using regex to match certain text after selecting with xpath

for example `Huntsville,  Alabama  11111`

i want only `Alabama` which always come after comma
and i use `[^,]*$` to get text after comma 
but i can't seem to find a way to exclude numbers or returns only the letters

another exmaple when i want to get the numbers after the comma i use `[^[0-9],]*$`
but when i tried to tweak it with anything else it only return numbers or nothing.

Comment: [`[?<=,\s*][a-zA-Z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/nHgjwa/1) is a wrong answer. `[?<=,\s*]` matches a `?`, `<`, `=`, `,` whitespace or `*` chars, it is not a lookbehind. That is why it matches a space and then `Alabama`. A lookbehind is a `(?<=,\s*)` that will only work with Python PyPi regex module, .NET regex and new ECMAScript 2018 JavaScript regex. I added [another answer that should work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874851/3832970), see below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[?<=,\s*][a-zA-Z]+` You can try this.

Explanation:

`?<=` => lookbehind to match a string but not include in capture group

`,\s*` => match comma followed by 0 or more spaces

`[a-zA-Z]+` => match letters only (one or more)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer , it worked with this [?<=,\s*][a-zA-Z]+

Answer (score 0):

To match a letter word after the last comma, you may use

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?=[^,]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sF8edQ/2).

**Details**

- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?=[^,]*$)` - followed with 0+ chars other than `,` up to the end of the string.

To match 1 or more words in the same context, use

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*(?=[^,]*$)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sF8edQ/3).

The `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*` part matches zero or more consequent occurrences of 1+ whitespaces and 1+ ASCII letters.